# Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in client4.ovpn:88: ca (2.4.7)

Tags: openvpn

I want to set path for client rsa files. but get this error:

> Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in
>   client3.ovpn:3: ca (2.4.7)

the config file:

```
client 
tls-client 
ca C:/Program Files/OpenVPN/config/ca.crt 
cert C:/Program Files/OpenVPN/config/client.crt 
key C:/Program Files/OpenVPN/config/client.key 
tls-crypt C:/Program Files/OpenVPN/config/myvpn.tlsauth 
remote-cert-eku "TLS Web Client Authentication" 
proto udp 
remote <server ip> 1194 udp 
dev tun 
topology subnet 
pull 
user nobody 
group nobody
```

Answer (score 2):

just using `""` around path make it worked

```
ca "C:/Program Files/OpenVPN/config/ca.crt"
```